# Create an agreement for two signers via Rest API

Tags: adobe, echosign

How can we create an agreement using a library document using a library document which will be singed by two signers? I know how to do the same using echo sign web application using this tutorial: https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/help/send-agreement---multiple-signers.html

I have created a template document in my dashboard for reuse purpose and I have added fields for recipients as well. But when I create agreement using that library document and from that agreement I create signing url. But both URLs only allow one of them to sign. If the second signer opens their link, the document shows as already signed. Can anyone tell me how can I create  and have my both signers complete the agreement using Rest API?

Answer (score 1):

please change your lines of **code from**

```
//Create recipient set info        
var recipientSetInfo = new agreementsModel.RecipientSetInfo();        
recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetMemberInfos(recipientSetMemberInfos);        
recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetRole(agreementsModel.RecipientSetInfo.RecipientSetRoleEnum.SIGNER);        
recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetName("fjenning@adobe.com");       

var recipientSetInfos = [];        
recipientSetInfos.push(recipientSetInfo);
```

**to this**

```
var recipientSetInfos = [];
        //Create recipient set info    
        for (var i = 0; i < recipientSetMemberInfos.length; i++) {
            var recipientSetInfo = new agreementsModel.RecipientSetInfo();
            recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetMemberInfos(recipientSetMemberInfos[i]);
            recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetRole(agreementsModel.RecipientSetInfo.RecipientSetRoleEnum.SIGNER);
            recipientSetInfo.setSigningOrder("SEQUENTIAL");
            recipientSetInfo.setRecipientSetName(" Recepients");

            recipientSetInfos.push(recipientSetInfo);
        }
```

Comment: Was facing exactly same issue thanks @MuhammadMohsane you made my day.